# How do I add a NOT clause to my SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to add a NOT clause to this SQL query:

```
Select 
    members.Member_Id, 
    members.Title, 
    members.FirstName, 
    members.LastName, 
    members.Po_Box, 
    members.Street, 
    members.City, 
    members.Del, 
    members.Mobile, 
    members.eMail, 
    members.WFTD, 
    ship_info.Renewal_Date
From 
    members 
Left Join
    ship_info on (members.Member_Id = ship_info.Member_Id)
Order By
    ship_info.Renewal_Date
```

The NOT clause is this:

```
Where Member_Id Not Between 2000 And 3000;
```

I have tried to place this line in different places, but get an error each time, and since Wamp reports errors in french, find it unhelpful.

Yes there are similar questions like this, but they confuse me more, as I don't understand them enough to modify my script accordingly. I don't know much about arrays and complex code.

I export data from the database for mail merge purposes, and Members whose Ids are in the 2000s are deleted Members, whose Id's were moved from their original Id to that of higher numbers, as I don't like deleting people permanently in case they change their mind later down the track.

Thank you.

Comment: Your `Member_Id` column exists in two tables in your query. You need to specify the table name.

Comment: You need to prefix Member_id with the name of a table as it's ambigious.

Comment: It would be better if you specify any error which you got, otherwise one error occurs with your where clause, you have to specify table alias because `Member_id` exists in both table so

Answer (score 2):

You could try it like this:

```
Select members.Member_Id
  ,members.Title
  ,members.FirstName
  ,members.LastName
  ,members.Po_Box
  ,members.Street
  ,members.City
  ,members.Del
  ,members.Mobile
  ,members.eMail
  ,members.WFTD
  ,ship_info.Renewal_Date
From members 
LEFT JOIN ship_info ON (members.Member_Id=ship_info.Member_Id)

WHERE (members.Member_ID < 2000 OR members.member_ID > 3000)

ORDER BY ship_info.Renewal_Date
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a JOIN and `member_id`  field resides in both tables of the JOIN, you must specify for which table you need the where statement. Try:

```
SELECT members.Member_Id
    ,members.Title
    ,members.FirstName
    ,members.LastName
    ,members.Po_Box
    ,members.Street
    ,members.City
    ,members.Del
    ,members.Mobile
    ,members.eMail
    ,members.WFTD
    ,ship_info.Renewal_Date
FROM members
LEFT JOIN ship_info ON (members.Member_Id = ship_info.Member_Id)
WHERE members.Member_Id NOT BETWEEN 2000
        AND 3000
ORDER BY ship_info.Renewal_Date
```

Answer (score 1):

According to "Database Administration Fundamentals", the following would be the appropriate syntax:

```
Select members.Member_Id
  ,members.Title
  ,members.FirstName
  ,members.LastName
  ,members.Po_Box
  ,members.Street
  ,members.City
  ,members.Del
  ,members.Mobile
  ,members.eMail
  ,members.WFTD
  ,ship_info.Renewal_Date
From members 
LEFT JOIN ship_info ON (members.Member_Id=ship_info.Member_Id)

WHERE NOT members.Member_Id BETWEEN 2000 AND 3000

ORDER BY ship_info.Renewal_Date ;
```

In the previously mentioned book, it states,

> " **JOIN** statements can be specified in either the **FROM** or the **WHERE**
>   clause, but it is recommended that you specify them in the **FROM** clause
>   ".

As for clause precedence, here is the correct order to follow:

```
SELECT     -- "what" we want
FROM       -- "where" to look for it
JOIN
WHERE      -- condition 
GROUP BY  
HAVING
ORDER BY   -- sorting order
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below should work, if not then please specify error which you got, you just need to prefix table name `members` (better if you use this table name as alias)

```
SELECT members.Member_Id
    ,members.Title
    ,members.FirstName
    ,members.LastName
    ,members.Po_Box
    ,members.Street
    ,members.City
    ,members.Del
    ,members.Mobile
    ,members.eMail
    ,members.WFTD
    ,ship_info.Renewal_Date
FROM members
LEFT JOIN ship_info ON (members.Member_Id = ship_info.Member_Id)
WHERE members.Member_Id NOT BETWEEN 2000
        AND 3000
ORDER BY ship_info.Renewal_Date
```